# How to sum two fields using CASE WHEN in SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to display the sum of field tries and the sum of points concatenated together but I get the sum only of the field tries.

```
SELECT
ContactName,
SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Event1' THEN tries || '/' || points END) AS "E1",
SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Event2' THEN tries || '/' || points END) AS "E2",
SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Event3' THEN tries || '/' || points END) AS "E3",

FROM names
WHERE
period = 2
GROUP BY
ContactName
```

Comment: Are you looking for `group_concat()`?

Comment: What is the syntax in my case in which I need a "/" between the two fields?

Comment: Try `group_concat(col_name separator '/')`

Answer (score 1):

I did the following by dividing the two sums

```
SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Event1' THEN tries END) || "/" || SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Event1' THEN points END) AS "E1"
```